# How do I create a input field dynamically in js

Tags: javascript

How do i create a input field using javascript, when i run it, it does not create the input.

I'm trying to delte two input fields and then create two more with id's and set them to type text.

This code works until it gets to the create element, i dont get any errors other than body.appendchild is not a function, imm confused.

```
var securityCode1;
var securityCode2;
var securityCode3;

function signUp() {
    var securityCode = document.getElementById('securityCode').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var code = [];
    var passwordArry = [];
    code = securityCode.slice();
    console.log(securityCode[5]);

    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * securityCode.length +1 );
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * securityCode.length + 1);
    var num3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * securityCode.length + 1);`

    securityCode1 = securityCode[num1];
    securityCode2 = securityCode[num2];
    securityCode3 = securityCode[num3];

    create();

}

function create() {
    securityCode.remove();
    password.remove();
    var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].removeAttribute('id');

    securityCodeE = document.createElement('input');
    securityCodeE.type = "text";

    securityCodeE.setAttribute('id', 'secuirtyCodeE');

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    body.appendChild(securityCodeE);

    var passwordE = document.createElement('INPUT');
    passwordE.setAttribute('id', 'passwordE');
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

`GetElementsByTagName` will return an array of elements, so you need to access the first one:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// appendChild will now work for you
body.appendChild(securityCodeE);
```

Comment: its not the error im worryed about i can fix that i wanna know why my codes not creating the input tags when its supposed to

Comment: You are creating two input elements, but they are not being added to the DOM.

Comment: You are not selecting the correct element, hence you are getting " body.appendchild is not a function  ". Select the correct elememnt as per above and you will be able to append!